# PHP and file manipulation

Tags: php, string, file-io

I was wondering if it is possible to open an xml file as a plain text file so I can read in each line and manipulate the text?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? you are asking for trouble. all the verbosity of xml with none of the semantic benifits.

Comment: I agree with others that you should use XML parser or DOMDocument but in case you want to know the answer is 'yes'. XML is simply a text file. You can read it with `file`,`file_get_contents`, `fread` or what ever you used to read a text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$xml_file = '/var/www/file.xml';
$contents = file_get_contents($xml_file); // Dumps the entire file into a single string
$contents = file($xml_file); // Dumps each line into an array
```

However, I would recommend using [`simplexml_load_file()`](http://php.net/simplexml_load_file) (even though you said you wanted to avoid it) because there is no guarantee as to how the xml will be formatted. It could all be on a single line or formatted with line-breaks in unexpected places.

Comment: I would like to use simplexml_load_file() but I can't figure out how to use it all that well. My biggest problem is extracting data from a single node.  I can never tell when an object is an array of objects or if its a object or a value in the object so I think I gonna stick with your example above right now and branch out a little later. Thanks for your help.

Comment: is_array() , is_object() , is_string()

Answer (score 1):

Why not use any of the XML parser/manipulator directly?

You can find those references at http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

If you have a nicely formatted XML file then,

```
$file = 'file.xml';

// get contents and normalize the newline
$xml_arr = file($file);
foreach($xml_arr as &$line){
  // do your manipulation to $line
}

$ctns = implode("\n",$xml_arr);
file_put_contents($file,$ctns); // write back
```

Comment: Why to split file context by `\r\n` if you can read file as line array by `file` function?

Comment: @Ivan - my bad. used to file_get_contents.

Answer (score 0):

To read file as array of strings use [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function:

```
$lines = file('your_xml_file.xml');
foreach($lines as $line) { 
    ## do the stuff for each line
}
```